# setting up a multi-language contact form

Tags: multistore, localisation, contact-us

I have a problem with a multi-language site, where I cannot make the contact form work for the 2nd language.

Here is my setup:

English contact form is at:
https://www.mysite.de/en/contacts

on submiting the forum it then loads:
https://www.mysite.de/en/contacts/index/

To customize the form, I made a dedicated page here:
the EN version is stored as a seperate tempalate here:
\app\design\frontend\ultimo\mytheme\template\contacts\form.phtml

the German version of the file is here:
\app\design\frontend\ultimo\mytheme\template\contacts\form-de.phtml

in this phtml, I have my form code, including the submit:

```
<div class="buttons-set">
    <p class="required"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
    <input type="text" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" style="display:none !important;" />
    <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
</div>
```

for DE, is the same code as EN.

The EN form is using the default /contacts/ setup of magento > there's no special CMS page for this. However, for the DE version, I made a dedicated page, where I load this code:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form-de.phtml"}}
```

This allows me to show the different form depending on the language.

**However, here's the problem:**

When I load the page from here: http://www.mysite.de/de/kontakt/ I see the form etc, everything looks good.

But on submit, it redirects to: http://www.mysite.de/contacts/index/post with a 404 page not found error.

I'm lost on how to sort this out, and appreciate any help! 
Thanks.

edit:
- could it be something to do with the URL storecode options I am using in the system setup? If so, what could be the workaround do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have solved the problem following the tips from here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21642846/contact-form-gives-me-a-404-page-in-magento

adding .. to the form action "/contacts/index/post" seems to have helped!

Comment: feel free to either accept this as the answer or post your complete code as it could help someone else in future.